# A batch file to minimize other applications

Tags: windows, firefox, vbscript, batch-file

How can i have a bat file which opens an application lets call it firefox.exe.how would i call the bat file or any other script ie vbs to minimize the application ie firefox.exe  then after lets say a minute or two close it.please mind you the `start\min` does not work?below is an example /part of my script?please help out?

```
"C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"  -tray
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try:

```
start /min "" firefox
```

.. or (if FireFox is your default browser):

```
start /min "" "http://google.com"
```

Comment: opens firefox ,but does not minimize the firefox window!

Comment: what platform are you using?am using windows xp,and doesnt seem to work?

Comment: also xp, both are working, but not, if FireFox is already open.

Comment: ok thanks!guess there is something wrong machine,coz it doesnt minimize whichever way,will try in another machine.did the firefox `tray` parameter work?

Comment: does using the firefox `tray` parameter work from your end?pliz reply?

Comment: no, it doesn't. there is no `/tray` option in the `start` command. Minimize to tray is in the responsibility of a windows application, not of cmd.

Comment: no the `tray` is a ff commandline parameter see the link http://kb.mozillazine.org/Command_line_arguments but it doesnt seem to work!

Comment: Perhaps this works on concrete case? I'm too on XP and this not work. My Firefox is 3.5.2 portable (if that relevant).

Answer (score 2):

The proper parameter would be `-turbo`, but it is long obsolete and probably not functional.

`start "path\firefox.exe http://example.com/file.html" /MIN`

might work better.

EDIT: Oops, it has already been suggested.

Comment: it opens the url in a new window which does not minimize ,and it opens with a default window.not what am loking for!

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried:
start /min C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe

using the forward slash?

Comment: funny enough your code minimizes the cmd prompt but not the firfox?

Comment: Change `Program Files` & `Mozilla Firefox` to 8.3 notation, to avoid space in the path. Or see Endoro's answer.

Answer (score 2):

here is how i solved the problem using a command line tool known as nircmd,i used the hide parameter to hide the firefox and it acctully works perfectly.see the code example.

```
START "" "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" -P "america" -no-remote http://hakikahost.com error.html
"nircmd.exe" win hide process "firefox.exe"
```

the link to nircmd ...[link](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html)

Comment: Apparently the relationship between NirCmd and FF has changed over the years. For me, using FF 85 on Win10 20H2, this command closed FF and erased all open tabs. What worked for me was nircmd win min process firefox.exe

Answer (score 1):

The `Firefox` is quite problematic in this respect. 
Here is the best work out I was reach with `VBScript`.

```
Firefox = """c:\path to\firefox.exe"""
Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set oFFox  = oShell.Exec(Firefox)

WScript.Sleep 1000
oShell.AppActivate oFFox.ProcessID

WScript.Sleep 1000
oShell.SendKeys "% (n)" ' minimize (Alt+SpaceBar,n)

WScript.Sleep 10 * 1000 ' wait 10 seconds
'next AppActivate call need Full and Exact title
oShell.AppActivate "Mozilla Firefox Start Page - Mozilla Firefox"

WScript.Sleep 1000
'oShell.SendKeys "% (r)"  ' restore (Alt+SpaceBar,r)
oShell.SendKeys "%{F4}"  ' close (Alt+F4)
```

**P.S.** Actually, restore command is redundant (I comment out that line).

**Note** that I not use `oShell.AppActivate oFFox.ProcessID` nor yet `oFFox.Terminate` because after minimize process both not work for me, therefore I use the title for the `AppActivate` and `SendKeys` to close the application.

Comment: Why do you use `SendKeys` to restore and close a window when you already have a `WshScriptExec` object that you can simply [`Terminate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yk84ffsf%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers - Only because that not work for me, see my update.

Comment: Hmm... both works just fine for me. I tested with SeaMonkey, not Firefox, though.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers - Can you test unruly Firefox as well.

Comment: Works with Firefox 20.0 as well (fresh install on Server 2003).

Answer (score 1):

Did you have a look at https://tn123.org/mintrayr/ addon? This can minimize firefox to try.

Comment: The addon adds a minimize to tray feature to firefox.

Comment: Oh... that addon has an option, to "always start minimized". In case it is ok with you.

Comment: oh wait... I think, it was some other addon, with similar functionality... But google for "firefox minimize to tray" :)

Comment: does this command line work from your end `"C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"  -tray` using the -tray parameter?pliz reply

Comment: nopes... FF doesn't support this option.. See this: http://kb.mozillazine.org/Command_line_arguments

Answer (score 0):

try with [***windowMode.bat***](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/.net/c/windowMode.bat):

```
call windwoMode -title "Mozilla Firefox" -mode minimized
```

though you'll need to know the starting letters of the window you want to minimize.