# BATCH How to minimize a program(process)

Tags: batch-file

I want to make a batch that will minimize an open procces or window eg.

My Firefox is open i want to minimize it similar to task managers option in process list

I dont want  to start firefox i want to minimize it while i opened it manually

Comment: possible duplicate of [A batch file to minimize other applications](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15773184/a-batch-file-to-minimize-other-applications)

Comment: nope that's not my case.  
I want it to minimize it WHILE it's open. Not just open it minimized

Comment: It is because there's no other solution anyway.

Comment: So you can only start it minimized?

Comment: No, there are several answers that show how to minimize the existing window.

Comment: link me i cant find it

Comment: [One](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15775248), [two](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15826963).

Comment: Or just Alt+Spacebar, then N.  If you want to script it, use a PowerShell command: `powershell "$s = new-object -COM Wscript.Shell; $s.AppActivate('Firefox'); $s.SendKeys('% n')"`