# Can't manage to make CMD launch a program using start

Tags: batch-file, cmd, thunderbird, minimized

I made a .bat file which is supposed to run Thunderbird minimized.
Here's what I put in it so far:

```
start /min "" C:\"Program Files (x86)"\"Mozilla Thunderbird"\thunderbird.exe runas /user:Administrator
```

I tried several tests:
- Removing /min
- Adding the runas option for administrator rights
- Adding the first empty quotes after start
- Writing the whole path into quotes
- ...etc.

Everything that happens is the .bat launches, but nothing furthermore happens.
I have no error in the CMD window.

Why isn't it working ??
My purpose is to put that .bat in startup folder so that Thunderbird launches minimized on startup.

I used to use an extension (MinimizeOnStartup) for Thunderbird, but it's no longer compatible with latest version and I couldn't manage to find any alternative.

I read through here, it wasn't enough to help:
[A batch file to minimize other applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15773184/a-batch-file-to-minimize-other-applications#)

Can you help me?
Thank you.

Using Windows 10.

Comment: the application has to support the `/min` switch. If it doesn't, this won't work. For example: `start /min "" "notepad.exe"` works fine. `Runas` is an application, not a parameter and completely useless here. Get used to always enclose the *whole path+filename*: `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Thunderbird\thunderbird.exe"` (not that this would help you here, it's just a good habit to avoid future problems).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the info.

Comment: `C:\PortableApps\ThunderbirdPortable\App\Thunderbird\thunderbird.exe -h |more`. There seems to be no option for minimizing.

Comment: A hint: I just visited [Command line arguments - Thunderbird](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Command_line_arguments_(Thunderbird)) and followed the first link to [Command Line Options - Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Command_Line_Options) and read on this page about __-tray__ with the description: *Start application minimized to system tray. Useful with autorun.* So create in your Windows menu `Startup` folder a shortcut file `Thunderbird.lnk` with the command line `"%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Mozilla Thunderbird\thunderbird.exe" -tray` and you should get what you want.

Comment: I already have the .lnk in startup, but it's the problem you mentioned yourself: it doesn't run minimized.

I tried the comment by Mofi, and what happens with it is "Windows does not recognize "-tray"".

If I remove "-tray", I get a CMD windows that's empty (only the current path appears).

Comment: You have not done what I have written. You should create a shortcut file `Thunderbird.lnk` which you can first create on your desktop. Simple shortcut creation is navigating in Windows Explorer to `thunderbird.exe`, right clicking on it and using _Send To -> Desktop (Create shortcut)_. You now have a `Thunderbird.lnk` file on your desktop. Next right click on shortcut `Thunderbird` on your desktop and left click on *Properties*. Append to command line a space and __-tray__. Close the dialog with __OK__ and double click on shortcut. Does it start Thunderbird minimized?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following (modify it accordingly)

```
cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Thunderbird\    
start /min thunderbird.exe runas /user:Administrator
```

Comment: Hi, thank you.
I tried that, same behavior. No error log, nothing else happens. :(

Answer (score 0):

A solution posted on reddit https://www.reddit.com/r/Thunderbird/comments/bnt6u3/ive_created_a_small_script_to_minimize/ ...

This is Windows only. You'll need NirCMD for this. NirCMD will trigger the "Minimize" Event after we've started Thunderbird. Get it here: https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html

The script:

START "" "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Thunderbird\thunderbird.exe"
timeout /T 3 /nobreak
"nircmd.exe" win min process "thunderbird.exe"